# Three.js - scaling the rendered image after processing?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

When I make my game fullscreen, the performance drops quite a bit, but it runs very smoothly if the screen is small.

Is there a way to render the game as a small screen, then draw that processed render scaled up? I want a retro look, so quality doesn't matter as much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the performance of you game by reducing the renderer's pixel ratio. Use a pattern like this one:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
renderer.setPixelRatio( 0.5 );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

three.js r.85